# I cannot show the value in html

Tags: python, html, django

I cannot show the value in html.
I wrote in views.py

```
def score_test(request):
    results = TestScore.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()
    print(results)
    return render(request, 'score_test.html',{'results': results})
```

in score_test.html

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2 class="result_title">Test Score</h2>

                <h3>Your score is 
                　{% for result in results.all %}
                    {% if result.score > 95 %}
                        <h4 class="one"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                    {% else %}
                        {% if result.score > 80 %}
                             <h4 class="two"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                    {% else %}
                        {% if result.score > 60 %}
                             <h4 class="three"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                    {% else %}
                        {% if result.score > 40 %}
                             <h4 class="four"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                    {% else %}
                             <h4 class="five"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                 {% endfor %}
                </h3>
            </div>
```

in models.py

```
class TestScore(models.Model):
    score = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

In  print(results) of views.py, I got `<function tc at 0x105a15d70>`, so I think I can get score of TestScore model in results. So, how can I fix this? Am I wrong to write if-else statement in template of score_test.html?

Comment: "In print(results) of views.py, I got <function tc at 0x105a15d70>" => this is NOT what you should have, and the code you posted can NOT yield this result (`results` should be a queryset). Please post the real code if you hope to get any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as OT because the code posted is obviously not the code that creates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"function tc at 0x105a15d70" is definitely not what `TestCore.objects.filter()` should return (it should be a queryset), and certainly not what the code you posted could yield, so no surprise you don't see anything in your template.

This being said there are a couple possible improvements to your code...

First, in your view:

```
results = TestScore.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()
```

the `.all()` is redundant. You just need:

```
results = TestScore.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

You could even just use the reverse relation (assuming you didn't specify a `related_name` in your `TestScore.user` field):

```
results = request.user.testscore_set.all()
```

Then in your templates:

```
            　{% for result in results.all %}
```

The ".all" is once again useless, and possibly (or not) the cause of your problem. But well, it's useless so don't use it ;)

```
            　{% for result in results %}
```

Then you could use `{% elif <condition> %} instead of nested`{% else %}{% if  %}`:

```
                {% if result.score > 95 %}
                    <h4 class="one"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                {% elif result.score > 80 %}
                     <h4 class="two"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                {% elif result.score > 60 %}
                     <h4 class="three"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                {% elif result.score > 40 %}
                     <h4 class="four"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                {% else %}
                     <h4 class="five"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
                {% endif %}
```

But using a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) would make your code simpler:

```
  # <yourapp>/templatetags/<yourlibname>.py

  from django import template
  register = template.Library()

  @register.filter
  def score_grade(score):
      try:
          score = int(score)
      except (TypeError, ValueError):
          # XXX should at least log the exception
          return ""

      if score > 95:
          return "one"
      elif score > 80:
          return "two"
      elif score > 60:
          return "three"
      elif score > 40:
          return "four"
      else:
          return "five"
```

and in your template:

```
{% load <yourlibname> %}

{% for result in results %}
  <h4 class="{{ result.score|score_grade }}"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It would sound a bit like the `all()` in views.py is redundant and `.all` in the template is useless. Calling it twice is probably the issue here, but calling it not at all would be wrong. It should be called exactly once, either in the view or in the template.

Comment: @Risadinha sorry but you're wrong.  `Model.objects.filter(...)` already returns a queryset so calling `.all()` on this queryset is totally useless - it only returns a clone of the existing queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elif command.

```
{% if result.score > 95 %}
    <h4 class="one"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
{% elif result.score > 80 %}
    <h4 class="two"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
...
{% else %}
    <h4 class="five"> {{ result.score }} </h4>
{% endif %}
```